# Looking for a dystopian sci-fi book in which the story is told through various characters' perspectives and people are hosts to some sort of infection

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

There are really only two characters I remember: a military man and a girl.

The girl lived in a camp with other survivors or people who weren't hosts (or brainwashed- I can't exactly remember). A notable character who lives with her is a boy with I believe red hair who asks to kiss her frequently(though I may be mistaking this part for another book). A helicopter flies by, and they wave their hands for attention, thinking that they would help them. The helicopter flies down to them and out comes military personnel. They then begin shooting at the camp's inhabitants and the girl flees (keep in mind that this is told in the POV of multiple characters, so she is just one of the many).

Later on, the girl gets injured in I believe her leg in a forest-esque place. It's snowing, and she is on the brink of death. She is then saved by a boy who is dressed similarly to a lumberjack. He bandages her, and has brown hair, and is muscular. When the girl is more conscious, she notices she has a change of clothes and asks if he was the one who bathed and dressed her. He looks away bashfully, a very human trait. Over the course of a few weeks, they bond with each other. But what's odd is that the lumberjack boy can't recall any of his memories with his family (a sign that someone has been brainwashed/ is a host), who he says he loves so dearly and has images of in his house, as well as the fact that the boy gets nervous and quickly changes the subject. One day she asks if he's been chipped (or is a host/brainwashed, can't really remember), and he looks down sullenly. He admits he is but that he's fallen in love with her. She takes that as her cue to leave. She storms out of the house and I believe he starts chasing her. There is also one scene where the lumberjack boy holds an axe above her head (there may also have been a mention of a gun, though that might not have been true).

In the scenes with the military man, there are also mentions of a facility that trains people to fight against the infected/hosts/brainwashed. They are told that people who do not pop up as a certain color on a scanner that they have been provided with are infected and should be killed immediately. It is revealed later, however, that it is they who are the villains and that the people they were killing were not, in fact, infected. They were killing normal people. This would also explain why the military men shot at the innocent civilians in the camp. The many characters meet up later, and they explode the facility.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall any details of the cover?

Comment: I read the novel back in 2017, though it was not a new release. As for the cover, I don't remember much. Actually, nothing at all. The only contents in the book that I'm certain of are the existence of a camp of survivors, an infected lumberjack boy who acted human, and a military facility with sinister intentions.

Comment: The bit about the army slaughtering a civilian refugee camp sounds like *The Fifth Wave* when the 4th wave (parasitized/fake humans) start trying to wipe out adult survivors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading a quick plot summary, I suspect this probably *is* [*The Fifth Wave*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1577764) (2013) by Rick Yancey.  ([Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16101128-the-5th-wave))

[image: Cover of "The 5th Wave" showing a person walking away along an overgrown path through a forest, silhouetted against a bright golden sky shining down the path, with the sun peeking over the treetops.]

Quoting a plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_5th_Wave_(series)#The_5th_Wave):

> The book opens in the midst of the Fourth Wave and follows Cassie's quest to find her brother, Sammy, after he is taken by U.S. Army soldiers. **Cassie is shot** by an Other-affiliated sniper, a "Silencer", from the woods on her trek, and is later **rescued by Evan Walker**, who nurses her back to health and agrees to help her find her brother. Meanwhile, Sammy arrives at Wright-Patterson AFB, which is now a "training camp" called Camp Haven. It is revealed over the course of the story that the soldiers are recruiting (truly, abducting) children into an army, telling them they are the last hope for fighting back against the Others. Sammy is placed in Squad 53 and befriends squadmate Ben Parish, who is coincidentally Cassie's long-lost crush from high school. After the two set out, Cassie and Evan are attacked by a squad from Wright-Patterson, and, after seeing how easily Evan dispatches them, **Cassie finds out that Evan was the Silencer who originally shot her. He then helped her because he had fallen in love and couldn't bring himself to kill her.** The two, though uneasily, coordinate a plan to extract Sammy then begin executing it. While deployed, Ben and his squadmate Ringer start to piece together their true purposes and learn that **Wright-Patterson is actually run by the Others. It is revealed that the Others are masquerading as a resistance force, abducting and training the children into a fighting force, which they will deploy as the Fifth Wave** to end humanity. Ben and Ringer decide to bolt with the rest of Squad 53, but Ben insists on going back for Sammy, who was left on base due to his age.

[emphasis added]

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you so much! It's been bugging me for the past few weeks and I'm glad to have finally found some closure.

Comment: @JMA If this is correct, please click on the checkmark under the voting arrows in the top left of this answer, so that future searchers will know this question has the right answer.  (It shows up in search results differently if it has an accepted answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Might this be *[Andromeda](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22378921-andromeda)* by Amy Bartelloni? It was published in 2014, and is the first book in the *[Andromeda Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/140078-andromeda)*.

[image: Cover of "Andromeda" showing a picture of barren ground surrounded by the ruins of a two-story brick factory-type wall, with a gray and cloudy sky above. The cover prominently displays the logo of the series, a gold circle containing a symbol composed of three abutting small circles with a larger half circle on either end.]

> Ten years after a pandemic swept the globe, survivors were forced into factions and camps in order to survive…
>
> Jade and Sera are two orphans who have found refuge in a government camp. It is there where Jade falls in love with a young soldier, Anyon. But Anyon has his own secrets, carefully guarding a past that involves Sera. But before Jade and Anyon admit their feelings to each other the camp is attacked and they’re separated.
>
> Jade knows to lead Sera to Albany, the last free camp in the east, but the road is dangerous.
>
> Not only must they dodge pockets of infection, but they are threatened by drifters and gangs. When they arrive in Albany, they find it deserted.
>
> Anyon and his friend Malachi are close on their heels, but not close enough. The Provisional Government is on a mission, and no one is quite prepared for what lies ahead…

I can't confirm whether there's a lumberjack character or not, but the plot summary does seem in line with your description, and according to [this review](http://www.booknerdsacrossamerica.com/2014/08/andromeda-by-amy-bartelloni.html), the POV does shift between various characters:

> Andromeda starts off with a very The Testing/I Am Legend feel. Jade and Sera are trying to make it to Albany, where they have agreed to meet up with friends from the government camp where they were living. **We see the journey through their eyes and also through the eyes of Anyon and Malachi, who they are going to meet. The story alternates points of view between the two sets of travelers and is interspersed with flashbacks that help us learn more about these characters**.
>
> It's a very intriguing concept, but unfortunately I felt that the first part was just a little too long. My little attention span just barely made it to Albany with the girls, and it didn't quite make it to the guys arriving later on. I skimmed the rest of the book from that point on and it seems like we get some big reveals after that point, and an intense looking showdown/final scenes with the government towards the end.

Comment: I've found the book I was searching for, but thank you so much for the book recommendation. I'll be sure to check it out when I get the chance.